# change innerHTML with text on squarespace

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, squarespace

i'm trying to take "sold out" on [this page](https://richie-siegel-bpsg.squarespace.com/new-products/) and change it to "coming soon."

right now i have the following but it's not working.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("product-mark sold-out").innerHTML = "Coming Soon";
};
```

Comment: The function in your code doesn't exist. You will need to use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks added an "s" but still not working.

Comment: The function returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not a single element. So you need to program accordingly.

Comment: @PM77-1 sorry im a bit new to this can you explain more?

Comment: @rs202 have you taken a gander at my solution below? :-)

Comment: @Petty thank you so much! how come you need the for loop to make it work? because it's a class?

Comment: @Petty, also, if i wanted to apply it to one specific image block is that possible? ie if the parent div has a specific id, can i have it only look in that div?

Comment: @rs202, yeah you could apply it, really, to whatever. You'd just want to use `getElementById('parentID').innerHTML = 'blah'`. Note ID are element specific, so you should only have 1 per element. So IMO you wouldn't need a loop to change just one.

Comment: The loop is to iterate over the collection, as pointed out by @PM77-1. We need only capture those and change those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
     //this captures all the elements with the spec classes
     var soldItems = document.getElementsByClassName('product-mark sold-out');

     //this changes each element 1 by 1 to new text
        for(var i=0; i<soldItems.length; i++){
           soldItems[i].innerHTML = "Coming Soon";
        }

}
```

That should take care of it!